# How to name a graph's title using the variable name supplied to as function argument in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a function whose only objective is to produce a bar graph. My dataset is called `south`.

```
# ......................................................................................
# Data for my example 
south = matrix(data = sample(x = c("A","B","C"), size = 1032, replace = T), ncol = 12)
# ......................................................................................
# Function to graph the count of 'A', 'B', and 'C' from 'data'
graphMaker = function(system){
system %>%
  as.data.frame() %>%
  gather(key = "Key", value = "Values") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Values, fill = Values)) +
  geom_bar() +
  labs(title = ________________)  
}
# ......................................................................................
```

> How do I get my graph's title to be string I supplied to my function's
>   argument `system`?

If I try `labs(title = system)`, I get a graph whose title is "C".

Ultimately, that's what I want my graph to look like.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `substitute`

```
labs(title = substitute(system))
```

Comment: @Mike It wouldn't work, from the helpfile you can read: `quote simply returns its argument. The argument is not evaluated and can be any R expression` so it will return `system` not the string in it.

Comment: @Mike, I did try `quote(system` but the result is a graph with "system" as the title. @Jilber Urbina, I didn't recall/was acquainted with the function `substitute`. It worked like a charm. Thank you for your input.